# In PyCharm IDE, what is the difference between Reformat Code and Auto-Indent Lines?

Tags: ide, pycharm, auto-indent

There are two options in the `Code` menu of PyCharm: **Reformat Code** and **Auto-Indent Lines**. They seem to be doing the same thing: reformatting the code. Is there any difference?

Reformat Code can process multiple files in the same directory. Is this the difference? One file vs. batch processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Auto-Indent Lines** does just that and nothing more.

**Reformat Code** does much more -- it can add missing/remove unnecessary spaces/braces, split statement into multiple lines etc -- all accordingly to your Code Style.